# does #define foo 1 ## ## 2 cause undefined behaviour?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, language-lawyer

6.10.3.3 of the c11 spec says

> each instance of a ## preprocessing token in the replacement list (not from an argument) is deleted and the preceding preprocessing token is concatenated with the following preprocessing token. [...] If the result is not a valid preprocessing token, the behavior is undefined.

So 1 ## ## would be replaced with 1##, which is not a valid preprocessing token, so the behaviour is undefined.
Is that correct?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
#define foo 1 ## ## 2
    printf("%d\n", foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling the above with `gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wpedantic` doesn't give any warnings, and the output is 12 as if there were only one `##`. Is that the expected output?

Comment: clang 9 produces `t.c:5:20: error: pasting formed '1##', an invalid preprocessing token
    printf("%d\n", foo);
                   ^
t.c:4:15: note: expanded from macro 'foo'
#define foo 1 ## ## 2`

Comment: ah thanks, I should have checked clang

Comment: undefined behavior may produces something reasonable (in your case) or an error (in my case) or any other behavior.

Comment: *"with the following preprocessing token"* - indicates it can't be an empty sequence of preprocessing tokens... so GCC may be doing something sane, but non-standard. It's treating the space as an empty sequence of tokens.

Comment: The way I see it, "*each instance of ## is deleted*" means `1 ## ## 2` should result in `1 2`, which (after token pasting) gives `12`.